# Magento 2 - Add step on checkout

Tags: magento2, layout, javascript, knockoutjs

I'm trying to add a new step to the normal workflow of magento 2 checkout, I follow the tutorial on magento dev page (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html)
but I don't get any result or any error.

Here my code:

I created a custom module (it result corretly load on magento) and I add the following file:

in /view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <!-- The new step you add -->
                                    <item name="check_login" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Shipping/js/view/check-login-view</item>
                                        <!--To display step content before shipping step "sortOrder" value should be < 1-->
                                        <!--To display step content between shipping step and payment step  1 < "sortOrder" < 2 -->
                                        <!--To display step content after payment step "sortOrder" > 2 -->
                                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <!--add here child component declaration for your step-->
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

then in /view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/check-login-view.js

```
define(
[
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
],
function (
    ko,
    Component,
    _,
    stepNavigator
) {
    'use strict';
    /**
     *
     * mystep - is the name of the component's .html template,
     * your_module_dir - is the name of the your module directory.
     *
     */
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Shipping/checkout/check-login'
        },

        //add here your logic to display step,
        isVisible: ko.observable(true),

        /**
         *
         * @returns {*}
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            // register your step
            stepNavigator.registerStep(
                //step code will be used as step content id in the component template
                'check_login',
                //step alias
                check_login,
                //step title value
                'Login / Registrati',
                //observable property with logic when display step or hide step
                this.isVisible,

                _.bind(this.navigate, this),

                /**
                 * sort order value
                 * 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;
                 * 10 < 'sort order value' < 20 : step displays between shipping and payment step
                 * 'sort order value' > 20 : step displays after payment step
                 */
                5
            );

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout step
         * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example some conditions
         * for switching to your custom step
         */
        navigate: function () {

        },

        /**
         * @returns void
         */
        navigateToNextStep: function () {
            stepNavigator.next();
        }
    });
});
```

finally in /view/frontend/web/template/checkout/check-login-view.js

```
<li id="check_login" data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible">
<div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Step Title'" data-role="title"></div>
<div id="checkout-step-title"
     class="step-content"
     data-role="content">

    <form data-bind="submit: navigateToNextStep" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
                    <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div></li>
```

The goal is to create a previous step where i check if the user is logged or not and I allow to login if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a new step to checkout page.

- Step 1: Create the .js file implementing the view model.
- Step 2: Create an .html template for the component.
- Step 3: Add the new step to the Checkout page layout.

I follow http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html
https://www.mageplaza.com/add-custom-checkout-step-magento-2.html

Your module directory structure should be like in **Magentodirectory/app/code/**
[image]

Here's **Registration.php** file

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
        'Lalitmohan_Checkoutstep',
        __DIR__);
```

**Module.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Lalitmohan_Checkoutstep" setup_version="1.0.0" >
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**checkout_index_index.xml** file

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <!-- The new step you add -->
                                        <item name="check-login-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Lalitmohan_Checkoutstep/js/view/checkout-login-step</item>
                                            <!--To display step content before shipping step "sortOrder" value should be < 1-->
                                            <!--To display step content between shipping step and payment step  1 < "sortOrder" < 2 -->
                                            <!--To display step content after payment step "sortOrder" > 2 -->
                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <!--add here child component declaration for your step-->
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**checkout-login-step.js** file

```
define(
    [
        'ko',
        'uiComponent',
        'underscore',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
        'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer'
    ],
    function (
        ko,
        Component,
        _,
        stepNavigator,
        customer
    ) {
        'use strict';
        /**
         * check-login - is the name of the component's .html template
         */
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Lalitmohan_Checkoutstep/check-login'
            },

            //add here your logic to display step,
            isVisible: ko.observable(true),
            isLogedIn: customer.isLoggedIn(),
            //step code will be used as step content id in the component template
            stepCode: 'isLogedCheck',
            //step title value
            stepTitle: 'custom step 2',

            /**
             *
             * @returns {*}
             */
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                // register your step
                stepNavigator.registerStep(
                    this.stepCode,
                    //step alias
                    null,
                    this.stepTitle,
                    //observable property with logic when display step or hide step
                    this.isVisible,

                    _.bind(this.navigate, this),

                    /**
                     * sort order value
                     * 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;
                     * 10 < 'sort order value' < 20 : step displays between shipping and payment step
                     * 'sort order value' > 20 : step displays after payment step
                     */
                    21
                );

                return this;
            },

            /**
             * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout step
             * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example some conditions
             * for switching to your custom step
             */
            navigate: function () {

            },

            /**
             * @returns void
             */
            navigateToNextStep: function () {
                stepNavigator.next();
            }
        });
    }
);
```

**check-login.html** file

```
<!--Use 'stepCode' as id attribute-->
<li data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible, attr: { id: stepCode }">
    <div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: stepTitle" data-role="title"></div>
    <div id="checkout-step-title"
         class="step-content"
         data-role="content">
        <p>The customer is <span data-bind="if: !isLogedIn">not</span> Logged-in</p>
        <form data-bind="submit: navigateToNextStep" novalidate="novalidate">
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <div class="primary">
                    <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
                        <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
```

***Note***: please replace **Lalitmohan** with your Namespace & **checkoutstep** by moduleName. Result should be like this.
[image]
[image]

Don't forget to run from your magento root directory after complete above all steps.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

and please check your module is enabled or not  or check 
[image]

Comment: I want to create an account link in your steps and its

Comment: @AkashPatel please create new question and link here...

Answer (score 0):

I think you do wrong over here : you need to write `/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/check-login-view.html` instead of `/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/check-login-view.js`

also chagne over here.

```
          stepNavigator.registerStep(

            'check_login',
            //step alias
            **'check_login'**,//you forgto to add ''(single quote)
            //step title value
            'Login / Registrati',
            //observable property with logic when display step or hide step
            this.isVisible,

            _.bind(this.navigate, this),


        );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Actually you made wrong on
template: 'Shipping/checkout/check-login'
to
template: 'Magento_Shipping/checkout/check-login'