# How to add new link on checkout page in Magento 2.2.4?

Tags: checkout, knockoutjs, html, magento2.2.4

I have created 1 custom tab on the checkout page and it's working fine I follow below link to add the tab on cart page.

[Magento 2 - Add step on checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132848/magento-2-add-step-on-checkout)

I want to add a link name as "Create an account".On click of that link, I want to redirect the page on create account page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Useful link how to add the link in a tag

[Best Way Of Getting Base URL Inside KnockoutJS .html File](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/189338/best-way-of-getting-base-url-inside-knockoutjs-html-file/#answer-196157)

**checkout-login-step.js file**

```
define(
    [
        'ko',
        'uiComponent',
        'underscore',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
        'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
        'mage/url'
    ],
    function (
        ko,
        Component,
        _,
        stepNavigator,
        customer,
        url
    ) {
        'use strict';
        /**
         * check-login - is the name of the component's .html template
         */
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Lalitmohan_Checkoutstep/check-login'
            },

            //add here your logic to display step,
            isVisible: ko.observable(true),
            isLogedIn: customer.isLoggedIn(),
            //step code will be used as step content id in the component template
            stepCode: 'isLogedCheck',
            //step title value
            stepTitle: 'custom step 2',

            /**
             *
             * @returns {*}
             */
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                // register your step
                stepNavigator.registerStep(
                    this.stepCode,
                    //step alias
                    null,
                    this.stepTitle,
                    //observable property with logic when display step or hide step
                    this.isVisible,

                    _.bind(this.navigate, this),

                    /**
                     * sort order value
                     * 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;
                     * 10 < 'sort order value' < 20 : step displays between shipping and payment step
                     * 'sort order value' > 20 : step displays after payment step
                     */
                    21
                );

                return this;
            },

            /**
             * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout step
             * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example some conditions
             * for switching to your custom step
             */
            navigate: function () {

            },
            getBaseUrl: function() {
                return url.build('customer/account/create');
            },
            /**
             * @returns void
             */
            navigateToNextStep: function () {
                stepNavigator.next();
            }
        });
    }
);
```

**check-login.html file**

```
<!--Use 'stepCode' as id attribute-->
<li data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible, attr: { id: stepCode }">
   <div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: stepTitle" data-role="title"></div>
   <div id="checkout-step-title"
        class="step-content"
        data-role="content">
       <p>You Are <span data-bind="if: isLogedIn">Already</span> <span data-bind="if: !isLogedIn">not</span> Logged-in</p>
       <span data-bind="if: !isLogedIn"><a href="#" data-bind="attr: { href: getBaseUrl() }" >Create an Account</a></span>
       <form data-bind="submit: navigateToNextStep" novalidate="novalidate">
           <div class="actions-toolbar">
               <div class="primary">
                   <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
                       <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                   </button>
               </div>
           </div>
       </form>
   </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your xml you can add a new item under the step like so:

```
 <item name="create-account-link" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">VENDOR_MODULE/js/view/create-account-link
     </item>
 </item>
```

Then create a js file for it.

web/js/view/create-account-link.js

```
define([
    'uiComponent'
], function (Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'VENDOR_MODULE/create-account-link'
        },

    });
});
```

Then create the html for it:
web/template/create-account-link.html

```
<a href.... you get the idea ... ></a>
```

Comment: how to write link <a href=" " ></a> ?

Comment: <a href="https://YOURURL/customer/account/create/">Create an account</a>

Something like this, there might be a Magento specific way to create the dynamic  path but i'm unsure how to do that.

Comment: @sanne thanks for your help but I got the answer from another link.

Comment: @Sanne, can we add link for New address button in checkout?

Comment: @jafarpinjar Probably, your best bet is to look at how Magento currently adds the new address button and just copy the functionality :)

Comment: @Sanne, yes i look into the default functionality, there the pop up is loading once clicked, need to add link for it, here is my question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/267933/adding-link-to-the-checkout-button-in-magento2/