# Magento 2, I Want to add or hide custom steps on checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs

I have created 1 custom tab on the checkout page and it's working fine I follow below link to add the tab on cart page.

[Magento 2 - Add step on checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132848/magento-2-add-step-on-checkout)

Then after I have added a Create an account link in the custom tab.I follow below link to add the Link

[Create an account link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/235880/magento-2-2-4-how-to-add-new-link-on-checkout-page/235891#235891)

Now I want to Remove the step for logging user. If the customer is logging then I want to remove 1st steps(Login) and it directly redirects on 2nd steps.

Answer (score -1):

Normally its the default behaviour when checking out while logged in you will see your addresses and you have to choose one, after that you get into the payment step.